# go routine with time duration

Tags: go, goroutine

The purpose of this code is to calculate each connected time between my computer and google.com using go routine.but the result seems wrong.why time keep increasing. what's go on here?

2013/12/04 16:10:41 www.google.com 597.175072ms

2013/12/04 16:10:41 www.google.com 608.161898ms

2013/12/04 16:10:41 www.google.com 614.527441ms

2013/12/04 16:10:41 www.google.com 620.51907ms

2013/12/04 16:10:41 www.google.com 630.052257ms

2013/12/04 16:10:42 www.google.com 654.539717ms

2013/12/04 16:10:42 www.google.com 659.144724ms

2013/12/04 16:10:42 www.google.com 1.282230659s

2013/12/04 16:10:42 www.google.com 1.353469764s

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    url := "http://www.google.com"
    for i := 0; i < 9; i++ {

        wg.Add(1)
        go request(url)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func dialTimeout(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    return net.DialTimeout(network, addr, time.Duration(1*time.Second))
}

func request(url string) {

    var t0, t1 time.Time

    transport := http.Transport{
        Dial: dialTimeout,
    }

    client := http.Client{
        Transport: &transport,
    }
    t0 = time.Now()
    _, err := client.Get(url)
    t1 = time.Now()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Println(url +" "+ t1.Sub(t0).String())
    wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: Not sure if goroutines are the problem here. Maybe the network? Or even Google doing some rate-limiting if you start hammering their serves?

Comment: not only google,i tried localhost,same result

Comment: Perhaps the connections are being serialised at some point?  I would have thought separate transports would mean separate connections, but perhaps it is happening at some other layer?

Comment: Still do not think the code is wrong. Replacing the network access with random sleeps shows the expected behaviour, see http://play.golang.org/p/xWd_cM4RC3 . So it must happen elsewhere as James suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is the explanation: Your code is a clever way to *sort* the 10 connection times from fastest to slowest. Each goroutine prints the needed time once it is finished, so longer connections are printed later. As all start basically at the same moment you see "increasing connection times" but nothing is increasing, the slowest are just slow and print at the end.

http://play.golang.org/p/MzgELyNh8B shows the effect.

Comment: I think this is a variant of Sleepsort.